# Are underconstrained type arguments equivalent to casts at value level?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, dependent-type

In Haskell, it's possible to leave type arguments underconstrained. Some known examples are collection `c` which implies type of elements `e` or lens where there exists an implied relationship between `s` and `a` as well as between `t` and `b` but nowhere to be found in the type signature.

Extensions like functional dependencies, type families allow more precise expression of relationships at type level. But are they equivalent to type-level casts when they don't constrain options fully?

While I believe the answer is "No" as value casts can "go wrong" at runtime but type level "casts" would have "go wrong" at compile time... But maybe that's what's happening when I don't align types properly?

Or are they more related to partial functions (or relations) at value level where some choices must be avoided?

Comment: Type casts are roughly equivalent to a `Typeable` constraint. Without that, there is no way to test or (safely) coerce a value whose type is unknown. E.g. `data T where T :: a -> T` allows `x = T True` but the boolean can never be extracted from that since there is no `Typeable` constraining `a`.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. A type variable left underconstrained will never unify with the "wrong" type, so if I have a list of integers, it'll never be "treated" as a list of doubles simply because a type variable said so. We have to explicitly call `map fromIntegral`, which does the type conversion *explicitly*.